# Not able to run the project in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a flutter project, I am getting this error repeatedly as per the below error log.

How should I resolve it??

```
> Compiler message:
> ../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/page_scaffold.dart:116:31:
> Error: The getter 'navigationBar' isn't defined for the class
> '_CupertinoPageScaffoldState'.
>  - '_CupertinoPageScaffoldState' is from 'package:flutter/src/cupertino/page_scaffold.dart'
> ('../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/page_scaffold.dart').
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
> a getter or field named 'navigationBar'.
>       final fullObstruction = navigationBar.shouldFullyObstruct(context) == null ||
> navigationBar.shouldFullyObstruct(context);
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import the following library in your route.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
```

Comment: no, it did not resolve the problem, and we never need to import this package

Comment: I was trying to configure this project `https://github.com/yahya997/flutterMessenger` in android studio, and the above issue, then I tried another project ,I faced the similar issue